# Que significa en Python el doble slah en una operación

Tags: python

viendo código por internet me encontré un fragmento de código que me pareció interesante pero no explicaban para que servía el "//"

codigo

```
# 6.Construir un programa que lea un número entero y determine si sus dos últimos dígitos son iguales.
numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
if numero % 10 == numero // 10 % 10:
    print("Los dos ultimos digitos son iguales")
```

en el condicional no se para que sirve el "//",  me gustaria saber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El doble slash en **Python3** indica una *división con resultado entero* y no decimal, ejemplo:

```
7/2 = 3.5
7//2 = 3
```

Más ejemplos aquí: https://programmerclick.com/article/98592283256/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!